# Check if an ember-data model is a subclass of another model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do I check if a class is a subclass of another given I only have access to the constructor not the instance?

```
//models/animal.js
export default DS.Model.extend({});

//models/dog.js
import Animal from './animal'
export default Animal.extend({});
```

Now I need to check if an object is of type Animal.

```
var Animal = store.modelFor('animal');
var Dog = store.modelFor('dog');

//fantasy method
Dog.isSubclassOf(Animal);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no super pretty way, but the `superclass` on the constructor has the super class that your class extended from.

```
var dogIsSubClass = Dog.constructor.superclass == Animal.constructor;
```

You can also use instanceof (easiest if you have a reference to the Animal class itself, instead of needing a record).

```
var dogIsSubClass = Dog instanceof Animal.constructor;
```